# Set SQL results to SESSION equivalent

Tags: php, session, foreach, key-value

With a table setup as follows:

```
CID   | FNAM | LNAME | CITY ------> 30 more fields
23432 | John |  Doe  | Denver
54342 | Jane |  Doe  | Boston
```

and when getting a result set this way (The query narrowed it down to 1 result):

```
$data = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
```

and using below to set each returned column in $row to a equivalent SESSION variable

```
foreach ($row AS $key=>$value) {$_SESSION["$key"]=$value;}
```

Why is it that I am getting a matching $_SESSION set with both the $key name, as well as a $_SESSION set with a numeric position in the array for each $row that was set to a session variable?:

echo $_SESSION['cid'];   results in 23432
echo $_SESSION['0'];     results in 23432

$_SESSION['cid'] is intended, but $_SESSION['0'] is not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using `mysqli_fetch_array` not `mysqli_fetch_assoc`

But anyway, you will get only the last row from your database, because you are always overwrite the given key. Loop through the fieldnames, and create an array, and add that array to a result array.

Comment: Please add to your answer that `mysqli_fetch_array()` always returns both numeric and associative elements... By using the flag `MYSQLI_ASSOC` you can change the behavior of the function and it works just as well as `mysql_fetch_assoc()`. Source: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: Thanks for pointing out something more obvious than I thought, also thanks for the additional comment on alternative flag.